# Get value data <td> javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, jquery-ui-sortable

How to get the td value when the data dragged? I need help, thankyou.

> Here the javascript :

```
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).sortable({
connectWith: ".connected"
});
$( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).disableSelection();
$( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).sortable({ //here i want to alert the value when stop dragging
stop: function( event, ui ) {
var val1 = $("td").innerHTML;
alert(val1);
}
});
});
</script>
```

> and here the html code:

```
<?php if(!empty($query)){?>
<table id="todo" name="todo" class="table table-bordered" style='width:150px'><thead>
<tr>
<th style="text-align:center;background-color:#eee">TO DO</th>
</tr>
</thead>            
<tbody id="sortable1" class="connected">
<?php foreach($query as $row):?>
<tr>
<td style="width:150px;background-color:#eee" id="<?php echo $row->list;?>" name="<?php echo $row->list;?>" value="<?php echo $row->list;?>"><?php echo $row->list;?></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach;}?> 
</tbody> 
</table>
<table id="today" name="today" class="table table-bordered" style='width:150px'>
<thead>
<tr>
<th class="ui-state-highlight" style="text-align:center">TODAY</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="sortable2" class="connected">
</tbody>
</table>
```

I don't know where my fault. Please give me an answers.

Answer (score 0):

Replace here

```
var val1 = $("td").first().html();//first() to ensure only
```

Comment: But it also get first value, so how to get another value? not just first td, thank you

Comment: as i see in your example , it was a just one td at initial , if you call all td's html it will generate in multiplicity

Comment: not call all td, i mean call the TD when dragging, just to put value the TD dragging

Answer (score 0):

Inside `stop:` event listener, try following thing:

```
stop: function( event, ui ) {
    var val1 = $(ui.item).html(); //ui.item is a jQuery object representing the current dragged element
    alert(val1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I found the answer :
`start: function(event, ui) {
      val1 = $(ui.item).find('td').attr('id');
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
      alert(document.getElementById(val1).innerHTML);
    }`

Comment: does adding code into `start:` handler is really needed? I think `stop:` is sufficient as same `$(ui.item)` is available in `stop:` too.

Comment: yes, on start i put the ID and then on stop i put the innerHTML from that ID

Answer (score -1):

Replace

```
var val1 = $("td").innerHTML;
```

With

```
var val1 = $("td").val();
```

http://api.jquery.com/val/

Comment: val() for a td... sure??